# Hidden files show up in Nautilus recent files

Tags: 13.10, nautilus, hidden-files

I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 and have a hidden folder. Using the privacy app in the system settings I have excluded this folder from the dash this works well enough although I would prefer to be able to exclude all hidden files/folders from the dash rather than excluding based on specific folders.

The problem though is that files in this hidden folder still show up in Nautilus' recent files. I don't really want to disable that feature altogether but can I prevent it showing hidden files only? (I would have assumed that should be default behaviour?)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how you hid them, but there is another way. Simply edit the name and put a "." in front of it. For example, if the name is "test.txt", then rename it to ".text.txt". Same thing for folder. If it is still there, press ctrl-h.

Note: Hiding Files is just a convient way of not displaying files that are only for internal purposes. They are easy to find. If you want to secure your files, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedHome.

Comment: No no no no no no no.

Comment: @Rinzwind What is the problem? Aren't I correct in saying that the "." does not in anyway encrypt it. The link is from the official Ubuntu help, in case actually encrypting it is what they want.

Comment: No, changing the file name is wrong. Adding a dot to a file name can mess things up if that file depends on software to function.

Comment: He never said it was essential to his software.

Comment: Yes a "." hides them, but they still appear in recent files - that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Nautilus has a special feature for this. Create a file with name `.hidden` in a directory and put a list of the files you want to hide in this file.

You can use a command like this to put them in that file:

```
cd ~/Downloads/
touch .hidden
ls . -1 * | sudo tee -a ~/.hidden
```

would put all files in the Downloads directory in the file .hidden and all files will disappear from view. Adjust it to your liking ;)

1 caveat: I have not tested this with the recent files but I would consider it a bug if it did not work like this ;)

Comment: It doesn't work like that... maybe a bug then?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no management mechanism for Nautilus' recent files.
activity-log-manager only works for Dash.